# Code design to avoid instantiating an empty object

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am writing some code to register two images.  I am using inheritance where the base class is `Image` and the subclasses are `ImageType1` and `ImageType2`.

```
class Image:
    # Note: I don't have an __init__ fx bc there are no attributes to initialize.
    # Is this appropriate?
    def sweep_left(self, image)
        # loop to find a specific pixel
        return row, col # return row and col of pixel
    
    def sweep_right(self, image)
        # loop to find a specific pixel
        return row, col # return row and col of pixel

    def sweep(self, image):
        left_row, left_col  = self.sweep_left(image)
        right_row, right_col  = self.sweep_right(image)
        return left_row, left_col, right_row, right_col

    def register(self, img1, img2):
        ref_left_row, ref_left_col, ref_right_row, ref_right_col = self.sweep(img1)
        reg_left_row, reg_left_col, reg_right_row, reg_right_col = self.sweep(img2)
        registered_img2 = #some calcs with variables above
        return registered_img2

class ImageType1(Image):
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image        

    def process_image_type_1(self):
        # Do some image processing using skimage
        processed_img = skimage_functions(image)
        return processed_img

class ImageType2(Image):
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image
        
    def process_image_type_2(self):
        # Do some image processing using skimage
        processed_img = skimage_functions(image)
        return processed_img
```

The following code runs successfully....

```
image1 = ImageType1(one_image)
image1_processed = image1.process_image_type_1()

image2 = ImageType2(another_image)
image2_processed = image2.process_image_type_2()

reg = Image()
register_images = reg.register(image1_processed, image2_processed)
```

However, I don't understand why this code returns an error.  Initially I thought it wouldn't even work because there is no obj Image, but after running it seems as though it 'kinda' worked, just needs 1 more argument. Can someone explain the details here?

```
register_images = Image.register(image1_processed, image2_processed)
```

> TypeError: Image.register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'img2'

How would you design the code to use method 2, e.g. `Image.register(image1_processed, image2_processed)`?

UPDATE: To hopefully clear some things up removed some generalities and added code snippets.

Comment: `reg.register` is a bound method, which when called with two arguments will supply `reg` as the first argument implicitly. `Image.register` is just the original function, which takes 3 arguments but you are only providing two.

Comment: You might be thinking about using `Image().register(...)`, which would invoke the method on an otherwise empty image. But, it looks like `register` should probably be a class or static method, if not a standalone function, rather than an instance method.

Comment: the first argument of `self` refers to the instance `Image()` rather than the object `Image`. If you wish to make a class method static  you can use the builtin decorator `@staticmethod` which doesn't pass a reference to the instance. Alternatively you can use `@classmethod` which will pass a reference to the object `cls` rather than an instance `self`

Comment: None of this code makes sense to me. Why don't any of the methods use attributes of `self`? You shouldn't be using so many global variables. What does `register` do with the two images?

Comment: You don't explain why the two derived classes should inherit from `Image` at all. As your question stands it would be simpler to have no `Image` class nor any inheritance, but instead a free function `def register(img1, img2):` Alternatively you could push up the `__init__()` method to `Image` as they are currently identical.

Comment: If you call a method of a class without instantiating the class, then you are treating that method just like a stand-alone function. Therefore the method can't have `self` as an attribute as there is no `self`. It begs the question why you would stick it in a class besides maybe code organization. I assume there is more going on in your `image` class though since your code doesn't make sense as-is, and if that's the case, then why would you not instantiate your class?

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the response.  I was unaware you could use `Image().register(...)`.  That clears things up.
@Barmar Could you expand on the global variable use.  I thought variables are local to the functions they are within?  I updated the code to give more examples which include self.  The question was too general it seems.  `register` is essentially aligning multimodal imagery.